# Renaming a file and appending a digit if a file already exists

Tags: rename, mv

I want to write a script that will rename a file and append a digit at the end if a file already exists.

```
mv a.txt b.txt
```

Since b.txt already exists, b.txt.1 will be the renamed file and if i do it again with I will get b.txt.2 because b.txt exists and b.txt.1 exists

I know there is a option with mv, mv --backup, but that gives me  b.txt~.1~, but i don't want the ~ before and after it. Is there another option just to append the digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yse. Since you expressed your willingness to write a script, here's what you need to know to accomplish that:

1. Test whether a file exists: The shell expression `[ -e filename ]`. See the `man` page for the many other tests you can perform. In order to make people better readers of `man` pages, I suggest that they get used to learning how to search for items within long `man` pages. Typcially, modern linux'es configure their `man` command to use the `less` browser. With that, one can perform searches using `/` and a regex, so documentation of an option (which will almost always start a line) such as `-e` can be found by `/^ *-e`. Repeat by just pressing `/`.
2. Remove a suffix extension from a filename: The shell expression `${var%.*}` will do that,  so save the filename in a variable, and perform that on the variable to get the file's basename.
3. Get the suffix extension of a filename: `${var##*.}`. Again, see the `man` page for your shell (eg. `man sh`, `man bash`)
4. Create a new filename: Something like `new="${old%.*}${counter}${old##*.}"`
5. So, you want to perform a `while` loop, checking that a new filename doesn't exist, and if it does exist, increment a variable. Once it doesn't exist, perform the `mv` using that filename as the target.
6. Incrementing a variable in shell scripting can be performed this way: `count=$((++count))`.

Comment: do you mind if i pm u what i've written

Comment: @Rashad : I'm not sure how you would do that, but if you mark the answer as accepted, I wouldn't mind. Maybe what you should do is mark my answer as accepted, and then add at the end of your question a section labeled "UPDATE:" followed by your script.

Answer (score 0):

According to `info '(coreutils) Backup options'` **there is no way to get just a number as the suffix.** `mv --backup=numbered` results in what you've already seen, `mv --suffix=''` results in just a `~` suffix (despite the documentation), and combining into `mv --backup=numbered --suffix=''` ignores the suffix.